# Remove all instances of a record if condition is met

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to remove all instances of a record if the value in the `flag` field is `4`. (this means they have unsubscribed from the email list)

Sample data:

```
Customer#       Email          Name   CustomerType   Flag
   001      email@email.com    Bob       Vet          1
   001      email@email.com    Bob       Med          2
   001      email@email.com    Bob       Pod          4
```

So since there is an instance that this record has a `Flag` of `4`, all 3 should be removed from this query. They don't need to actually be deleted from the database, I just don't need the data to come up in my query. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the customer number is what links the records together, you can use a `not exists` clause:

```
select *
  from tbl t1
 where not exists (select *
                    from tbl t2
                   where t2.[Customer#] = t1.[Customer#]
                     and t2.Flag = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks sstan, I believe this will work for me. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
delete from sample
    where customer# in (select customer# from sample as s2 where flag = 4);
```

EDIT:

You can readily adapt this to a `select`:

```
select s.*
from sample s
where customer# not in (select customer# from sample as s2 where flag = 4);
```

Comment: I'm sure you just missed this point: "They don't need to actually be deleted from the database"

Comment: @xQbert . . . Thank you, I did miss that.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Three approaches.

1. use Not exists
2. use a where not in
3. use a join

Below is the join:  Sstan provided the not exists and Gordon more or less provided the where in but change to not in and a select and you'd have it as well.

Without table size volume of translations and index information I can't say which would offer the best performance though the not exists is the strong favorite.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableName A
LEFT JOIN TableName B
 on A.Customer# = B.Customer#
and B.Flag = 4
WHERE B.Customer# is null
```

This does a self join but only to a set of records that are flagged as 4.  it then excludes those records which have a match; returning only customer#'s which don't have a 4.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It was very helpful in working this out.